# Getting audio levels outside of the JVM

Tags: java, audio

I need to check the audio levels of any application running on Windows, and when the audio reaches a certain point, execute some code. The problem i have is that doing something like this:

```
Mixer.Info[] mixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
for (Mixer.Info mixerInfo : mixers) {
    Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);
    try {
        mixer.open();
        Line.Info[] lines = mixer.getSourceLineInfo();
        for (Line.Info linfo : lines)
            System.out.println(((SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(linfo)).getLevel());                
    } 
    catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

wouldn't work if im not mistaken because it can't check audio being played outside of the JVM. Is this correct?

If it is correct then can i use JNA to map a Windows dll and use its functions to check for the audio levels?

Any idea of how i can manage to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So, i found an implementation if anyone else is looking for the solution to this. Credits to the owner of the github!

https://github.com/serezhka/clickerbot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/serezhka/clickerbot/jna/SoundUtil.java